# jspm and aurelia not working in webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, ecmascript-6, aurelia, jspm

i've gone through [Scott Allen's Hello World app](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/04/07/aurelia-hello-world-with-asp-net-5.aspx), and have my Aurelia app working perfectly in visual studio.

For some reason, I'm unable to get the same result in WebStorm. My index.html body looks like:

```
<body aurelia-app>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import("aurelia-bootstrapper");        
    </script>
</body>
```

and I'm met with a console error

> Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.14.0" at http://localhost:63342/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/bootstrapper@0.14.0.js

the full error looks like:

[image]
it looks like it's trying to grab a file `boostrapper@0.14.0.js`, whne that's actually a folder.  Why am I unable to get the exact same code working in webstorm as in visual studio?

Here's my bootstrapper section of my config:

```
"github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.14.0": {
  "aurelia-event-aggregator": "github:aurelia/event-aggregator@0.6.1",
  "aurelia-framework": "github:aurelia/framework@0.13.2",
  "aurelia-history": "github:aurelia/history@0.6.0",
  "aurelia-history-browser": "github:aurelia/history-browser@0.6.1",
  "aurelia-loader-default": "github:aurelia/loader-default@0.9.0",
  "aurelia-logging-console": "github:aurelia/logging-console@0.6.0",
  "aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.10.1",
  "aurelia-templating": "github:aurelia/templating@0.13.2",
  "aurelia-templating-binding": "github:aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.0",
  "aurelia-templating-resources": "github:aurelia/templating-resources@0.13.0",
  "aurelia-templating-router": "github:aurelia/templating-router@0.14.0",
  "core-js": "npm:core-js@0.9.18"
},
```

and running `jspm -v` yields

```
C:\Users\Jones\WebstormProjects\Aurelia>jspm -v
0.15.7
Running against global jspm install.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh.  It was completely urelated to Aurelia, and totally related to my ineptitude as a web developer.

WebStorm hosts it's server at `http://localhost:port/ProjectName/...`

<s>Hence, when I added my project name in the paths in `config.js`:</s>

```
"paths": {
  "*": "*.js",
  "github:*": "Aurelia/jspm_packages/github/*.js",
  "npm:*": "Aurelia/jspm_packages/npm/*.js"
}
```

it all worked.

the more-correct way is to add the client url `/ProjectName` when running `jspm init`, and everything is handled for you.

Comment: Will you elaborate on this please? I've been looking into aurelia, and while I know it isn't officially supported in webstorm, review your top information and attempting it is failing for me. I've adapted baseURL: "ProjectName/". I've even added in paths... "*":"src/*" with no results.

Answer (score 4):

> looks like it's trying to grab a file boostrapper@0.14.0.js, whne that's actually a folder.

Actually there should be a folder *and* a .js like this:

```
jspm_packages\github\aurelia\bootstrapper@0.14.0.js // descriptor
jspm_packages\github\aurelia\bootstrapper@0.14.0    // folder
```

In your case, the .js seems to be missing.  I've hit the before and I'm still not sure when/why this occurs, but when nothing else seems to fix it, I've just brute-forced...

(assuming windows b/c you mentioned visual studio)

Open cmd:

```
cd C:\Users\Jones\WebstormProjects\Aurelia
jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper --force
```

The `--force` *should* replace the missing .js:

```
jspm_packages\github\aurelia\bootstrapper@0.14.0.js
```

If that file is present, restart your app and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks @shanonvi.  This wasn't my problem, but it gave me the kick I needed to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check your `config.js` file and search for `bootstrapper` to see what version you have installed?  Also please let me know of your version of jspm in console -

```
$ jspm -v
```

As long as bootstrapper is at 0.14.0 in your config.js and your jspm is a recent version (not beta) you should be good, if not let me know or try our gitter channel @ http://gitter.im/aurelia/discuss - if you don't get immediate resolution PM me and we can work through the issue and I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks for the response and help.  I've posted the information you asked for - and to me it seems to check out.  I'll jump on the `gitter` channel later today when I have more time if I'm unable to further resolve it.